# Trying to install opencv-python with pip keep raising errors. What to do?

Tags: pip, opencv, python

I'm trying to install opencv-python through pip but I keep getting an error. How do I go about it

I used normal 'pip install opencv-python' and it gave me an error, I downloaded the whl file and it still gave me an error

It gives me an error message like:

> ```py
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-python
> ```

Comment: did you try into a virtualenv or conda environment ?

Comment: None of them just on my normal command line

Comment: Try `pip install opencv-contrib-python`

Comment: If you’re on Linux try `sudo apt-get install python-opencv`

Comment: pip install opencv-contrib-python still gives the same error message

Answer (score 0):

Please check the version of pip in your machine. Most probably the issue is due to non compatible version of pip. Try upgrading pip using 'pip install --upgrade pip'